# Error when calling getUserProfile from Spring social facebook

Tags: facebook, spring-social-facebook

when I call org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile() I get the folllowing error:

```
org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (address) on node type (User)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:91) ~[FacebookErrorHandler.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:59) ~[FacebookErrorHandler.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:641) ~[RestTemplate.class:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:597) ~[RestTemplate.class:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572) ~[RestTemplate.class:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280) ~[RestTemplate.class:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:214) ~[FacebookTemplate.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:209) ~[FacebookTemplate.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:53) ~[UserTemplate.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:49) ~[UserTemplate.class:2.0.2.RELEASE]
```

I believe this is a new error... though this code was not well exercised before this.

The profile fields that are requested are in `org.springframework.social.facebook.api.UserOperations` and the "address" field does appear in this list.

The problem might also be permissions although again I'm under the impression I have the required permission.

Though looking at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user, address does not appear in the list and all the entries in UserTemplate that I've tried are there...

btw, UserOperations list is

```
    static final String[] PROFILE_FIELDS = {
    "id", "about", "age_range", "address", "bio", "birthday", "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education", "email", 
    "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people", "installed", "install_type",
    "is_verified", "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", "name", "name_format", 
    "political", "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status", "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other", 
    "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id", "updated_time", "verified", "video_upload_limits", "viewer_can_send_gift", 
    "website", "work"
};
```

Comment: There is no `address` field on the `user` object. Facebook doesn’t give out user’s home addresses via API.

Answer (score 3):

This was fixed (e.g., the "address" field removed) in Spring Social Facebook 2.0.3.RELEASE.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I could not upgrade to Facebook 2.0.3 RELEASE so I changed my code from using the getUserProfile method to specifically ask for only what I needed... (With pre 2.0.3 getUserProfile included the full user profile - including address).

I was doing:

```
String adminUser = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile().getName();
```

And because all I needed was the user's name I changed this to:

```
String adminUser = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, "name").getName();
```